# Rails video transforming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

is there any possibility to change a video with rails?

what I want is if someone opens a video on my page and "stream" it there should be printed a timecode into the video. So if he download the the video the timecode should be present as well.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You will need to modify the actual video file, this is not something that comes out of the box with rails.

Comment: Okay are there gems  with those functionality

Comment: could you provide a link ? i'd like to check it out then

Comment: Not at the moment :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Q:

> is there any possibility to change a video with rails?

**No**, Ruby on Rails itself does not provide any way to modify a content of a video.

Comment: Is there a gem to do someting like that?